# Teradata SQL- Order by date and flag rows between two events

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, teradata

I have a dataset like this 
[image]

Where I have a field called, 'SALES_CHANGE' which identifies on which date sales either significantly rose or dropped. I'm interested in creating another field that flags periods between drops and rises. I.e., like this: 
[image]
Where the flag starts when there is a drop and then stops right before the next rise. And then starts again when there's another drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata supports `lag() ignore nulls`.  So, your rule is basically that the current row or most recent row with a value is `'DROP'`.  For that . . .

```
select t.*,
       (case when sale_change = 'DROP' or prev_sale_change = 'DROP'
             then 'DIP'
        end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(sale_change ignore nulls) over (order by id_date) as prev_sale_change
      from t
     ) t;
```

You don't really need the subquery -- the lag can be in the outer `case` expression.

Comment: I wish more RDBMSes supported `IGNORE NULLS`

Comment: What about Oracle? BTW, IGNORE NULLS and RESPECT NULLS are ANSI SQL functionality.

Comment: @jarlh . . . MySQL, Postgres (and I am guessing all Postgres-derived databases), SQL Server, MariaDB, and BigQuery are among the databases that support `lag()` but not `ignore null`s.  Oracle, DB2, and Teradata do support them.

Comment: Seems like also Informix support IGNORE NULLS.

Comment: Simpler using `case when last_value(sale_change ignore nulls) over (order by id_date) = 'DROP' then 'DIP' end`